# Eclipse win32 on 64bit Windows

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, swt, 32bit-64bit

Are there any drawbacks, bugs when running Eclipse for Windows 32bit on Windows 64bit?

What Java distribution should be selected (32/64) for 32bit Eclipse ?

(The issue may be not so simple as Eclipse has OS specific SWT GUI libraries distributed within .zip  )

Comment: And why do you want to run a 32bit app on a 64bit OS? It just makes no sense.

Comment: No, 32-bit applications will run fine on Windows 64. Eclipse ships with its own JRE and it will not be an issue. You can select any Java distribution you want to build your projects against, 32 or 64 bit will both work with 32-bit Eclipse. The runtime you build your projects against is not tied to the runtime used to run Eclipse.

Comment: @JasonC i think you should post this comment as an answer, and lose your perfect 1111 rep

Comment: @fge may be the most efficient way memory wise.

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Ha, I didn't even notice. Make a wish! I will post it as an answer as soon as I make sure I wasn't talking out of my arse when I said Eclipse ships with its own JRE.

Comment: @JasonC the downloadable versions of eclipse do not include a JRE.

Comment: Dammit! I wonder why I thought it did. Nope, I have no business posting an answer here. Next question please.

Comment: @fge For example you can put Eclipse32 on USB stick and use on both Windows (e.g. at work and at home)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install 32bit JDK to use with 32bit Eclipse.

Using 32bit software on Windows x64 was common practice until Windows 64bit stack became smoothly working.

Ref

- [32bit eclipse and 64bit java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892740/32bit-eclipse-and-64bit-java-programm)
- [Running 32bit eclipse with 32bit jvm on windows 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240631/running-32bit-eclipse-with-32bit-jvm-on-windows-64bit)
- [Should I use Eclipse 32bits or 64bits on my new machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652677/should-i-use-eclipse-32bits-or-64bits-on-my-new-machine)

Extended as having 2 JDK(or JRE) on one system may become an issue:

from http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F

> If a JVM is installed in the `eclipse/jre` directory, Eclipse will use it; otherwise the launcher will consult the `eclipse.ini` file and the system path variable. Eclipse DOES NOT consult the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

To explicitly specify a JVM of your choice, you can use the `-vm` command line argument:

`eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\javaw.exe`              ''start Java by executing the specified java executable
   `eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll`         ''start Java by loading the jvm in the eclipse process